# Data grid refresh

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagrid

I have developed a C# windows application using SQL Server as back end. I have a form that takes in user data and the data is showed in a datagrid.

However the challenge is, I need this data refreshed constantly upon input. I have tried possible refresh means but no solution.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Assignment_Prudence
{
    public partial class StudentDeatilsPage : Form
    {
        public StudentDeatilsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void StudentDeatilsPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'studentsDatabseDataSet.Table' 
            // table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.studentsDatabseDataSet.Table);
            dataGridView1.Update();
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post what you tried ? and what is not working out ?

Comment: some source code would be helpful

Comment: If u share some code we can help you out on this

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ TAG your question correctly! - __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView`!! This is wrong and confusing and and bound to get wrong answers wasting everybody's time.. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Comment: Its a windows form application.. For a datagrid view..sorry for the mistake there

Answer (score -1):

i think u need to refresh the data what you need that means u need to call that binding method please find below code for ur reference

```
  private void StudentDeatilsPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.studentsDatabseDataSet.Table);
        LoadData();
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        List<Employee> StudentList = (ke.SearchStudent(txtname.Text, txtCity.Text)).ToList();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = StudentList ;
        dataGridView1.DataBind(); 
    }
```

Try this this will definitely work for ur requirement